# How to execute shutdown command from Node.js app on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, raspberry-pi

I have a headless Raspberry Pi running a simple NodeJS application.

The only interface I have attached to the Pi is a single push-button which starts and stops a timelapse video recording.

I know it's not good practice to cut the power to the Pi without a proper shutdown, so I want to add a shutdown command to Node.

Using ShellJS, I can do this very simply - if the user holds down the push-button for five seconds, I can call

```
shell.exec('sudo shutdown -h now');
```

which will shutdown the Pi.  This works as expected when I'm connected to the Pi via ssh and I call the node command myself ('node app.js'). But my goal is to have my Node app running automatically on startup. I'm doing that by using '/etc/rc.local' to call the script on boot:

```
su pi -c 'node /path/to/app.js'
```

In this case the shutdown command does not work, and I don't even know how to access the node console to see what kind of error it's throwing. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Does the `pi` user have sudo privs? Also, it may be a `$PATH` issue, try using the full paths to both `sudo` and `shutdown`.

Comment: That works much better, thank you. But can you explain why? Since I'm learning Linux I would love to understand when & why I need to provide full paths for commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you start processes from `/etc/rc.local`, those processes will be started with a limited `$PATH` variable (the `$PATH` variable contains a list of directories where to find executable programs, so you don't have to start those programs using their full path; instead, just their name will suffice).

This usually doesn't contain the paths to system binaries, like `shutdown`, which can be found in `/sbin`.

Your login shell most likely does add those system paths to `$PATH`, which is why—when starting your Node app from the command line—the shutdown executable works just fine.

But when the same Node app is started from `/etc/rc.local`, the shutdown executable can't be found in any of the directories in `$PATH`, and trying to execute it will result in an error.

You can solve this by either using the full path to the shutdown executable, or by augmenting the `$PATH` variable in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
# /etc/rc.local
export PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
su pi -c 'node /path/to/app.js'
```